# image map question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dictionary

I am searching for a script similar to [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/) or [Map Hilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) which will allow me to control the colours of the map areas. I found found a few that work well but I also want to control the unactive state. This is where most fall flat. What I want to accomplish is on page load a map will appear and each map area will be a different shade of blue according to population density.

Please let me know if anyone knows of a good script I can use, cheers

UPDATED
Thanks guys, I managed to solve this using the map hilight script

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that all day, I only just figured out how to do it with map hilight right now, so it's solved, cheers

Comment: Mind posting what you made as an answer? Others with similar problems will benefit!

Comment: Sure but I can't answer my own question for a few hours, I'll update it tommorrow, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was actually really simple, just another case of RTFM or in this case, documentation. I used the Map Hilight script (http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/).

In the js file there is an option: alwaysOn: true, I set this to false. Then I added this class to every area tag: class="{fillOpacity:'0.5'}"

I used the fill opacity to change the opcacity for each area based on the population density. Cheers